# WPF designer exception; "An item with the same key had already been added"

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, exception, fonts, designer

I am working on an app that uses WPF. In the designer, whenever I select a Label object while the Properties window is open and the Text section is expanded, within a second the designer disappears and gets replaced with a modeless error dialog:

> (X) An Unhandled Exception has occurred
>
> Click here to reload the designer
>
> Details:
>
> > System.ArgumentException
> >
> > An item with the same key has already been added
> >
> > - At System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource Resource)
> > - At System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(...)
> > - At MS.Internal.FontFace.PhysicalFontFamily.ConvertDictionary(...)

I'm pretty sure the rest of it is irrelevant.

I'm still developing the code; it's not even running. The exception is occurring in VS Designer's code.

Obviously something is wrong with one of my fonts. How can I fix this?

**Edit** We've already tried stopping the font-related services and clearing the font cache.

Comment: is there a control template for text box in your project?

Comment: If there is, we've never created one on purpose. How would we see if there is one?

Comment: sorry I probably meant for Label. I think you should share the code you have created.

Comment: Share the code? There's no code! All the project is currently is a XAML file describing plain window with a bunch of Label and Ellipse objects!

Comment: Well it is hard to guess what it could be without seeing the project itself if it was my project I would start by creating a new object and then re-create the xaml by copying from the old project. There might be a reference somewhere that is causing havoc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**(Solved)**

Finally after hours of debugging found the solution.

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Preview and when I tried to open XAML file I got an error:

> System.ArgumentException
>
> An item with the same key has already been added
>
> At System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource
> Resource) At System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(...) At
> MS.Internal.FontFace.PhysicalFontFamily.ConvertDictionary(...)

That error didn't help much. So I created a local account and logged in with that new account. Then  I got a message

> There is a file or folder on you computer called C:\Program which
> would cause certain applications to not function correctly. Renaming
> it to C:\Program1 would solve this problem. Would you like to rename
> it now?

Once I deleted that file the XAML files appeared to be working.

So check in your C:\ if there is something different. Make sure you check all the hidden files also.

Comment: Useful info, thanks. That's very possible, I'll check it soon.

Comment: I got this Problem when crating a new/first WPF project in Visual Studio 2015 and this solved it. thx

Comment: Wow! thank you!! This was driving me nuts..Same issue and the file named Program was hidden on the rood of c: